# Selenium not performing click action

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape a table with multiple pages. The next page is obtained by clicking on the 'Next Page button' (See code snippet).

```
<a class="botons" id="btn2" href="javascript:void(0)">
 Next Page  
 <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>
</a>
```

Selenium finds the "button" and has no trouble "clicking" via the following code:

```
btn_next = self.browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Next Page")
btn_next.click()
```

However, the page just refreshes and the table doesn't update to its next page.

Any clues to what's going wrong here?

Edit: table can be found at https://www.proxy-list.download/HTTPS

Edit2:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
```

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

Comment: there are at least two event handlers firing there.... one is on the <body> tag... that one opens a new window and sets it to the same URL.  The other one is placed on the button itself, and populates the table but only if a certain var evaluates to true.  (this probably happens when the ad loads in the popunder)  Maybe try generating a click on the <body> tag and then a click on the button...  or execute a javascript to set the var "btn2ena === true"

Comment: you might also try just clicking it twice...  you'll probably also need to switch the driver to the new tab after this happens.  (adding the wait listed in the answers below will also be needed cause the button handler is added on pageload...)

Comment: @pcalkins This actually solved it! Thanks a bunch. If you submit your comments as an answer, I'll accept and close this thread.

Comment: good to hear... go ahead and post your own answer.  Not sure which solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is one **id** assigned to that button `btn2` and it's unique too.

You should give preference to **id** over **link Text**.

That said, **Next Page link** isn't present in **view point**.For that first you have to move the focus of driver like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser,10)
next_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "btn2")))
ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(next_page).perform()
next_page.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for you input, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue. The problem remains the same.

Comment: After running it, a new tab is opening ?

Comment: Sometimes a new tab opens for an advertisement. But selenium then still manages to scrape the first page of the table. So I doubt that it's causing any problems?

Comment: in my system, it is opening in new tab after execution, and first tab got blocked, I'm in private network. Ask your dev (If possible ) to give a workaround in QA Env.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.botons[id^='btn2'] i.fas.fa-long-arrow-alt-right"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='botons' and normalize-space()='Next Page']/i[@class='fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for you input, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue. The problem remains the same.